# MPI in c. I don't receive what I send

Tags: c, mpi

I am new in MPI. I am trying to write some simple code. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ONE 0
#define TWO 1

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int dimension = 5;
    float ** matrix;
    float * mat1;
    float * mat2;
    int i,j,numNeighbor, processReceived,rank,size,retval;
    int k = 0;
    retval = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Request sendRequest[2], recvRequest[2];
    MPI_Status status[2];
    MPI_Datatype row;

    MPI_Type_vector(dimension, 1, dimension, MPI_FLOAT, &row);
    MPI_Type_commit(&row);

    if(retval != MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, retval);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    mat1 = malloc(dimension*sizeof(float));
    mat2 = malloc(dimension*sizeof(float));
    matrix = malloc(dimension*sizeof(float*));
    for(i=0; i<dimension; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(dimension*sizeof(float));        
    }

    printf("MATRIX OF RANK %d\n", rank);
    for(i=0; i<dimension; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<dimension; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = (float)(rank+1)*(i*2+j);
            printf("%2.1f ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    MPI_Isend(&(matrix[0][0]), 1, row, 1-rank, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, sendRequest + ONE);
    MPI_Isend(&(matrix[0][0]), dimension, MPI_FLOAT, 1-rank, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, sendRequest + TWO);

    MPI_Irecv(mat1,dimension, MPI_FLOAT, 1-rank, 1-rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, recvRequest + ONE);
    MPI_Irecv(mat2,dimension, MPI_FLOAT, 1-rank, 1-rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, recvRequest + TWO);


    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        MPI_Waitany(2,recvRequest, &processReceived, status);
        printf("Process Received : %d of rank : %d\n", processReceived,rank);
        if(processReceived == ONE)
        {
            printf("%d ",rank);
            for(j=0; j<dimension; j++)  printf("# %6.1f ",mat1[j]);
            printf("\n");
        }

        if(processReceived == TWO)
        {
            printf("%d ",rank);
            for(j=0; j<dimension; j++)  printf("@ %6.1f ",mat2[j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    MPI_Waitall(2, sendRequest, status);
    free(mat1);
    free(mat2);
    for(i=0;i<dimension;i++) free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
    MPI_Type_free(&row);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

```
MATRIX OF RANK 1
0.0 2.0 4.0 6.0 8.0 
4.0 6.0 8.0 10.0 12.0 
8.0 10.0 12.0 14.0 16.0 
12.0 14.0 16.0 18.0 20.0 
16.0 18.0 20.0 22.0 24.0 

MATRIX OF RANK 0
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 
2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 
6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 
8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 

Process Received : 0 of rank : 0
0 #    0.0 #    0.0 #   12.0 #   14.0 #   16.0 
Process Received : 1 of rank : 0
0 @    0.0 @    0.0 @   12.0 @   14.0 @   16.0 
Process Received : 0 of rank : 1
1 #    0.0 #    0.0 #    6.0 #    7.0 #    8.0 
Process Received : 1 of rank : 1
1 @    0.0 @    0.0 @    6.0 @    7.0 @    8.0
```

What I think I am doing with this program is that I send one row and one column of each process to the other process. Then I print whatever i received in each process. But as you can see this is not the output i thought i would have. What i am waiting for is something like:

**example of output:**

```
Process Received : 0 of rank : 0
    0 #    0.0 #    2.0 #   4.0 #   6.0 #   8.0

Process Received : 1 of rank : 0
    0 #    0.0 #    4.0 #   8.0 #   12.0 #   16.0
```

Can anyone explain me what i haven't got very well? This is the only function that i use so you can run it in your own machines. For this example you can use only 2 processes.

```
mpiexec -n 2 ./name_exe
```

Comment: Your code cannot work because your `matrix` doesn't store the data linearly. You need to allocate `matrix[0] = malloc(dimension*dimension*sizeof(float));` and adjust `for (i=0; i<dimension; i++) matrix[i]=matrix[i-1]+dimension;`. Then maybe it'll work.

Comment: I see your point in the first correction. But your second one leads to segmentation fault. `for (i=0; i<dimension; i++) matrix[i]=matrix[i-1]+dimension;` Your first one is `matrix[-1]`

Comment: My bad, I meant `for (i=1; i<dimension; i++) matrix[i]=matrix[i-1]+dimension;`

Comment: Well it runs like a charm now! :D Thank you very much! Post it as an answer if you wish, in order to approve and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that the data storage in `matrix` isn't linear. As it is defined in the code at the moment, `matrix` is an array of pointers, all of which point to some independent memory segments.

However, your code assumes that `&matrix[0][0]` points to the beginning of a linearised row-major matrix.

Well, to solve the issue, you simply need to comply with this by allocating matrix the following way:

```
matrix = malloc(dimension*sizeof(float*)); //nothing new here
matrix[0] = malloc(dimension*dimension*sizeof(float));
for(i=1; i<dimension; i++) matrix[i]=matrix[i-1]+dimension;
```

Then you use `matrix` exactly as before, but for the freeing part, which becomes:

```
free(matrix[0]);
free(matrix);
```

With this, the code should work.