# MPI_Send doesn't send all elements of 2D-matrix

Tags: c, mpi, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to send a 2D matrix via MPI to another node, but it just doesn't sends all arguments.

Sending-Part:
(matrixB.matrixPointer is an Array of double* and in the elements are arrays of double)

```
rows = 6;
matrixB.size = 5;
MPI_Send(matrixB.matrixPointer[offset], rows*(matrixB.size+1)+10, MPI_DOUBLE, destination, dataMessage, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Resceiving-Part:

```
rows = 6;
matrixB.size = 5;
MPI_Recv(matrixB.matrixPointer[offset], rows*(matrixB.size+1)+10, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, dataMessage, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

This works for a 6x6 matrix, but without the offset of +10, which shouldn't be necessary, there are 8 values missing.
Can you help me?

Comment: Is your 2D data stored contiguously in memory? If not, then you've got  a problem... See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34417162/5239503) for more details on how to address it.

Comment: We'll have to see more code to be able to do anything with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks the problem was, that the array was not stored in contiguously memory! :)